# FTP File Locked

Tags: windows, ftp

We're having an issue that only started last week, where files on the FTP are being locked.

The site is an asp site. The main asp file, as well as all files referenced as an include file on that file are constantly locked.

The only way we're able to update these files is by renaming the web.config first, then updating the file, and renaming the web.config back.

As mentioned, this issue only started last week - we've been fine until then.

Our site is hosted by Rackspace. They don't have an answer as to why our files would be locked, except that "the web.config" is causing it as "it's in use".

My questions are:

1. What is causing this sudden lock?
2. Is there any way to update a locked file without bringing our site down by renaming the web.config?

Comment: Please specify which OS you are using.

Comment: @mdpc "ASP site" makes it pretty likely it's Windows...

Comment: BTW, there are ASP extensions that are suitable for Linux/UNIX environment.

Comment: As I said, "pretty likely".

Comment: Yup, windows it is.

Comment: Can you run Microsoft SysInternals' handle.exe to confirm which process has the file(s) locked?

Comment: This is a shared hosting environment - managed by Rackspace. So I don't think I'm able to do that.

Comment: This was an internal Rackspace issue, which occurred after they've upgraded part of their system. They downgraded us, and as of this time the issue is resolved.